# Создание собственного поискового движка для сайта на php

Tags: php, поиск

Хочу создать поисковый движок для блога. Проблема заключается в большом количестве информации, которую нужно хранить.

На мой взгляд, оптимальный вариант - хранить статьи в XML файлах, а в базе данных хранить ключевые слова(то есть саму статью, заголовок и комментарии, в которых убраны поторяющиеся слова) и ссылку на файл. Все вроде ничего, но при поиске по базе данных только в 1 000 000 записей, время поиска составляет 3.7 секунды, что уже много !

Есть другой вариант: хранить только слова с ссылкой на другую базу данных или файл, где собственно и перечислены статьи, в которых встречаются эти слова. Тесты не проводил, но, на мой взгляд, время поиска не сократится...

Какой есть выход из этой ситуации ? Каким образом современные поисковые движки находят информацию за доли секунды ?

Comment: %-) google://elastic search sphinx fulltext indexing reverse index и т.д.

Comment: даже не пытайтесь. особенно на php. особенно без понимания такой штуки, как индексы.

Comment: Я пытался индексировать текст, но особых улучшений так и не добился ! Увы...

Comment: @Ярослав вам нужно прочесть или очень много книг или несколько очень хороших статей. И быть гением. И разобраться в том, как работают компьютеры. Что гуглить - я выше указал. Etki абсолютно прав насчет php, в нем вы можете только прототипировать индексирование (в питоне тоже и т.д.) Но с ходу ворваться на рынок поисковых движков у вас не получится. Но вы старайтесь, откроете для себя много интересного.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, будем разбираться !

Comment: Посмотрите https://cse.google.ru/cse/ Может, для вашего блога подойдет.

Comment: Да, видел... Оформление не понравилось: как на мой взгляд поиск с надписью гугл внутри выглядит, мягко говоря, не солидно. ...но как вариант подойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это будет не полноценный ответ, а пояснение на примере ElasticSearch, но, прочитав его, поймете, почему здесь нет полной инструкции (и почему проще использовать тот же ElasticSearch).

В вопросе не указаны конкретные требования к движку, поэтому формализуем их так: поиск по документам с произвольными полями (строки, булевы значения, числа, даты, айпи-адреса, геоточки), как точный, так и неточный, количество документов - *несчетно много*, точный поиск должен выполняться за миллисекунды, неточный - за сотни миллисекунд при поступлении сотен и десятков запросов в секунду соответственно, движок должен предоставлять возможности для линейного горизонтального масштабирования, т.е. увеличению производительности пропорционально размеру кластера. Предполагается, что у каждого документа есть первичный ключ, по которому он может быть уникально идентифицирован.

Для того, чтобы производить поиск по какому-то атрибуту документа, движок должен построить карту соответствий <атрибут-документы>, чтобы при нахождении соответствии по атрибуту находить вслед за ним и сам соответствующий документ.

```
document a:
  type: user
  admin: true

document b:
  type: user
  admin: true

document c:
  type: user
  admin: false
  nickname: bob

index type:
  user -> a, b, c

index admin:
  true -> a, b
  false -> c

index nickname:
  bob -> c
```

Такая структура называется инвертированным индексом, и с ней есть некоторое количество проблем.
Во-первых, он стремится быть большим. Чем больше документов, тем больше он разрастается, и его становится все больше и больше, поэтому нельзя надеяться, что он поместится в оперативку. Да и, в экстремальных случаях, в один файл на одной машине.
Во-вторых, его нельзя частично перестроить во время добавления нового документа. Эта структура данных должна быть максимально оптимизирована для поиска, для этого нужно эффективно располагать ее в памяти, это (как минимум) убивает запрет на ссылки, а, следовательно, чтобы добавить новый документ в индекс, нужно перестроить все, что будет идти за его позицией. Потенциально это гигабайты данных и не очень быстрая операция даже при размещении всего в оперативке, и в момент каждого перестроения индекс был бы недоступен.
Поэтому де-факто эффективный поиск ведется по неизменяемым структурам данных, которые регулярно заменяются на более свежие версии.
Примерно такая теория лежит за индексами, позволяющими искать документы по их атрибутам. Здесь есть огромное поле для оптимизаций (например, для того, чтобы не оперировать гигантскими индексами, ElasticSearch бьет их на сегменты и добивается таким образом near-realtime поиска, когда документы появляются в индексе в течение секунды после добавления).

Но сам движок индексов, конечно, умеет искать документы только по конкретному индексу и совпадению, а поисковый движок должен уметь работать сразу с несколькими атрибутами. Поэтому здесь встает две проблемы: работа с дополнительным слоем абстракции (запросами к движку) и непосредственно объединение запросов. Язык запросов может быть любым (хоть SQL), а вот с объединением все немного сложней. Я боюсь сейчас наврать, но, насколько знаю, в момент выполнения запроса движок создает битсеты для каждого отдельного подзапроса, после чего объединяет их, чтобы получить общий набор документов, удовлетворяющих условию. Про все вот это вот можно почитать по запросу [boolean model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Boolean_model) (я не читал, каюсь).

После этого всего вступает еще одно требование к поисковому движку, без которого он практически бесполезен - результаты требуется ранжировать. Здесь в дело вступает еще одна модель, [tf/idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), которая позволяет относительно дешевыми методами получить общую значимость совпадений в документе относительно других совпадений. Если представить, что мы производим поиск по словам "главный" и "распределитель", то, очевидно, документы, у которых десять совпадений слова "главный" и одно слова "распределитель" должны быть менее релевантны, чем документы с десятью совпадениями "распределитель" и одним "главный". Используя модель tf/idf, движок нормализует количество совпадений запроса с документом относительно совпадений запроса со всеми документами вообще; если слово "главный" встречается в каждом втором документе, то его влияние на релевантность запроса минимально, и при расчете "веса" совпадения движок просто поделит реальный вес на (грубо говоря) количество совпадающих документов вообще.
Все вышеописанное не является обязательным, но применяется по умолчанию в движке ElasticSearch.

После всей этой теории можно наконец коснуться более сложных частей движка - например, поиска по тексту (пока что еще даже не нечеткого поиска). ПРоблема с текстом в том, что для поиска документа нужен обратный индекс, а обратный индекс из всей строки целиком не построишь (в этом случае у десятикилобайтового текста был бы индекс, совпадающий исключительно с этим же десятикилобайтовом текстом). Поэтому текст надо разбить на составляющие (обычно - слова), по которым будет построен индекс и впоследствии будет вестись поиск. Это просто невероятно отвратительный момент, который в любом случае отдается на откуп пользователю (т.к. только он знает, по каким совпадениям ему нужен поиск), однако сам движок должен предоставлять функционал для нарезки текста на составляющие. и здесь нужно предоставить следующий функционал:

- Возможность убирания окончания
- Возможность включать цифры, скобки, прочие символы в нарезанный результат
- Разделять или не разделять слова по дефису
- Заранее избавляться от слишком частоупотребимых слов (вычистить все предлоги)
- Превратить Ä в А
- Превратить какой-то входной поток данных в *фонетический аналог* ("здесь" превратить в "сдесь", чтобы даже неуч смог найти что-то этим движком)

И, конечно, все это должно работать для какого-то разумного набора разных языков (в нашем случае - как минимум русского и английского).
После того, как текстовый документ превратился в набор *токенов* и по ним построился индекс, для корректного поиска по нему нужно еще и проделывать каждый раз для входной поисковой строки - чтобы вводящий "что-то здесь не курится" пользователь искал документы, совпадающие в индексе с "сдесь" и "курица" (кстати, обратите внимание на последний пример - в этом случае запрос очень просто превратился в невалидный, пользователь рискует получить документы по домашнему хозяйству, это еще один балл в корзину "сложность реализации поисковой машины").

И, наконец, нечеткий поиск. После всего вышеописанного здесь относительно простая схема: берется каждый токен в индексе, сравнивается с преобразованным запросом, вычисляется расстояние Левенштейна, в процессе все несовпадающие токены (и документы вместе с ними) выкидываются в тот момент, когда превышают максимальное допустимое расстояние Левенштейна. Впрочем, не стоит забывать и про то, что пользователь движка наверняка захочет подсветить совпадения и исправления, а это еще очень много боли по внедрению.

После того, как эта машина построена и вроде бы работает, встает еще одна проблема - проблема масштабирования движка. Здесь начинается очень специфичная боль:

- Все данные не умещаются на одной физической машине
- При распределении данных по машинам для получения результатов надо выполнить запрос **на всех машинах** и объединить результаты
- В результате польза от масштабирования равна нулю, потому что каждый запрос уходит на все машины, и по факту любая машина обслуживает столько же запросов
- Теперь осталось приплюсовать сюда желание пользователя агрегировать результаты (аналог GROUP BY) и пагинацию результатов, чтобы получить полнейший ад

ElasticSearch использует для этого хак, который при правильном использовании облегчает жизнь. Он изначально делит хранилище документов на шарды - отдельные юниты исполнения - после чего распределяет эти шарды по кластеру. Шарды, как правило, дублируются, поэтому просто при случайном распределении запросов по кластеру можно добиться некоторого снижения нагрузки на каждый отдельный узел. Однако ElasticSearch позволяет хранить и искать на определенном шарде, используя для этого один из атрибутов документа: например, если вы храните географические названия, и вам нужн оискать улицы, то вы в качестве такого атрибута можете использовать идентификатор города, в котором расположена улица, и ElasticSearch потревожит только тот шард, на котором хранятся данные по этому городу.

Это все не описывает и десятой части проблем, которые требуется решить при реализации поискового движка (и далеко не все они сформулированы корректно), поэтому я рекомендую вам взять ElasticSearch, Solr, Sphinx или, если будет желание, что-то из инструментов для собственного построения индексов (e.g. Lucene, на котором построен ElasticSearch - сам-то он поиском и не занимается, ха-ха - или YoctoDB), и использовать уже готовые решения.

Comment: И действительно, после всех выше описанных проблем и трудностей,я даже и не думаю создавать свой собственный поисковый движок !

А вам, Etki, большое спасибо за потраченное на статью время !Очень познавательный материал и, я думаю, не только для меня.

Comment: @Ярослав Хорошо, что проблемы и трудности не остановили Сергея Брина и Ларри Пейджа. Спасибо, Etki

Comment: @postrel У каждого свой талант.